# PHP sending emails through random email accounts

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm working on a website that allows you to send emails without registering, and without specifying a sender. You enter the recipient's address, subject, body and send. My problem is sending the message. What I'm trying to achieve:

User clicked send -> Subject,recipient,body sent to PHP -> Server validates the information -> Server creates a random email account -> Server sends the email through the random account created -> Server deletes the account

I'm stuck at the random email account creation step. How do I achieve this with PHP ***without*** having to pay for my own SMTP server and ***without*** having to use my own gmail/hotmail account.

I googl'd the hell out of this issue and I can't find an answer.

Thanks!

BTW
I'm using Apache to "host" on my own Ubuntu

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, sounds pretty spammy to me. Why can't the email be from the server address? Remember sendmail/qmail is free (in dollars, not in configuration time).

Comment: I tried qmail, but I'm getting an error 111 unable to find user alias. Can't get it to work =/

Answer (score 4):

> How do I achieve this with PHP without having to pay for my own SMTP server and without having to use my own gmail/hotmail account.

The way to create E-Mail accounts varies wildly from server software to server software, and is usually not possible from within PHP.

Depending on your server's configuration, though, that might not be necessary: If you set up a catch all address for a domain, many server configurations will allow you to send out mails from any E-Mail on that domain (e.g. `123456789@example.com`). Any responses will then go to that catch-all mailbox, the contents of which you will probably want to discard.

You have to realize, though, that this is exactly how spam providers operate. Extreme caution is advised if you don't want to end up on all sorts of spam blacklists.

Comment: Yeah, and once your ip is banned you are screwed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I really don't want to get my server banned. Is there a safer way?

Comment: @MisterSir not really, no. Offering E-Mail services without registration is very likely to get misused very quickly anyway, at least if you're offering them publicly. That said, if you can control and validate *what* gets sent, you can always give it a try, but it's a risky business

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can create accounts or email accounts on a server, using PHP, as this supersedes PHP's permission level. Sending emails this way is a good way to get your server banned, FYI. Also, if you insist on sending emails like this, why not just specify a dummy `From:` email address? It would essentially be the same thing as creating a dummy account anyhow.

You may also want to use the `-f` switch, for PHP's `mail()`. See php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Wait, so how do sites like dispostable.com don't get their server banned? Maybe I could just do the same as those sites just shorten the dispose time and disallow inbox access?

Comment: @MisterSir sites like dispostable.com don't allow **sending** E-Mails, do they?

Comment: Not familiar with the site...but I just tried it out - doesn't look like you can send email, only receive.

Comment: I tried using a dummy header, didn't work. $message = $_POST['body'];
 $subject = $_POST['title'];
 $to = $_POST['recipient'];
 $headers = 'From: unimail@uni.com';
 
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); Didn't work

Comment: @MisterSir This works for me. May be your server configuration if it doesn't work. Try this code as is and see if you get an 'ok' response: `$message = 'Test message'; $subject = 'My test email'; $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; $headers = 'From: unimail@uni.com'; $sendMail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); if($sendMail) { echo 'ok'; } else { echo 'failed'; }`